# VBA, create a new sheet based on a list and give it a color

Tags: excel, vba, colors, tabs

I have a code that create a new sheet based on a list in one sheet called "Röd".
I try to give the new created sheet a color but dosent make anything to work? How do i color a new created sheet with my code?

```
Sub Röd()

    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheets
    

    'This Macro will create separate tabs based on a list in Distribution Tab A2 down

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Röd").Range("A3")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
    

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
         If SheetCheck(MyCell) = False And MyCell <> "" Then
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
            .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
    
    
    Next
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it. If you still have questions then simply ask.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Röd")
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Column A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Loop through the range
        For i = 3 To lRow
            '~~> Check if cell is not empty
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value2)) <> 0 Then
                '~~> Check if the sheet already exists
                If SheetCheck(.Range("A" & i)) = False Then
                    With ThisWorkbook
                        '~~> Add the sheet
                        .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
                        '~~> Color the tab
                        .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        '~~> Name the tab
                        .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = ws.Range("A" & i).Value2
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Function SheetCheck(MyCell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim wsht As Worksheet
    
    For Each wsht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsht.Name = MyCell.Value2 Then
            SheetCheck = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Error on "If SheetCheck(.Range("A" & i).Value2) = False Then". It says object required

Comment: `Function SheetCheck(MyCell As Range) As Boolean

Dim ws As Worksheet

SheetCheck = False
 
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 
    If ws.Name = MyCell Then
    
        SheetCheck = True
        
    End If
 
Next
 
End Function`

Comment: I saw how you write the color code, and used it in my code. Now it works, see my answer

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my code. it is how you are using the code `SheetCheck`. You declared the parameter as range `MyCell As Range`. See my updated post. Now it will work. You may have to refresh th epage to see it. All you have to do was change `If SheetCheck(.Range("A" & i).Value2) = False Then` to `If SheetCheck(.Range("A" & i)) = False Then` in my code

Comment: Yes, now your code works aswell! Thanks for the help! Do you know how to write a code if the name in a cell is longer then 30 character to use the first 30 character. And skip the rest to be able name the new sheet even if the cell name is longer than 30 character?

Comment: Check for `Left(.Range("A" & i).Value2,30)`

Comment: Where do i add it?

Comment: Two places. Change `If wsht.Name = MyCell.Value2 Then` to `If wsht.Name = Left(MyCell.Value2,30) Then` and then change `.Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = ws.Range("A" & i).Value2` to `.Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = Left(ws.Range("A" & i).Value2,30)`

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. I didn't write it correctly before.

```
Sub Röd()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheets
    
    'This Macro will create separate tabs based on a list in Distribution Tab A2 down

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Röd").Range("A3")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        If SheetCheck(MyCell) = False And MyCell <> "" Then
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'give the new tab color red
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```